# Network discovery accross vpn

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, vpn, network-discovery

I am home users using Wi-fi device to connect with the internet for my laptop and desktop computers.

I connect to my office network using VPN connection from my desktop and all work fine and able to see all my office computer under Network Option.

But while I click on network from my laptop, Still I am able to see all my office computers, while I do not connect to VPN from my laptop. What is the reason for it?

Comment: Is your desktop computer using a wired connection to that same Wi-fi device (aka router) or is it using a wireless connection ? It could be that your laptop has too much of a weak signal to have a stable connection to the VPN tunnel. Can you provide the error message (number) you get on you laptop (i.e. Error#800) ? Is it a Windows Client or another one such as Cisco AnyConnect, Sonicwall etc ...

Answer (score 0):

My Desktop is connected through wireless connection.

I do not want to connect My Laptop to VPN, but still My Laptop can see computers under network which is across VPN. Why?